# How to update listview after calling Asynctask to call webservice

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am calling a `webservice` through `asynctask`, to call the `webservice` i am calling one method named `makeRequest()` in `doInBackground()`, I am getting the response in another methods `success()`, In success method i am updating the `listview`

But i am getting error like

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."
```

Here Im adding my code.Im calling `synctask` from activity

```
new MyTask(this,urlAsString,sp).execute();
```

here is the Asynctask class

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog progress;

        String url;
        SharedPreferences sp;
        HomepageH2desk c;
          public MyTask(HomepageH2desk context,String url,SharedPreferences sp) {
            this.c = context;
            this.url = url;
            this.sp = sp;
            progress = new ProgressDialog(this.c);
            progress.setMessage("Loading...");
          }

          public void onPreExecute() {
            progress.show();
          }

          public Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
             c.getTickets(url,sp);
            return null;
            //progress.setMessage("Loading...");
          }

          public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            progress.dismiss();
          }
        }
```

Here im getting `webservice` response

```
 public void success(Object result) {

     list = (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) result;

    this.adapter.setList(list);
            this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

`listview` is not getting updated and showing error

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Help me to solve this problem...

Comment: where you are calling that notify data set changed ???

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should update your List like this.

```
Activity_name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
      list = (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) result;
      this.adapter.setList(list);
      this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Lalit: because it running in main thread so does it may cause ANR dialog ?

Answer (score 5):

Since this the error that comes up when you do some MainThread task in another thread.....

try This:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

public void run(){

     this.adapter.setList(list);
     this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

});
```

This code might have some errors But in simple Words.. add the notifyDataSetChanged call into runOnUiThread()  method. You will be Done..

OR this can also be DOne ( the perfect way )

add the following in your activity class

```
 private Handler handler = new Handler() {
     @Override
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        this.adapter.setList(list);
        adapter.setnotifyDataSetChanged();
     }
  };
```

Call this handler when and where you want to call the notifydatasetchanged like this

```
  handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Thanks
sHaH

Comment: hmmm so can u Mark it correct if it helps You ?? and also Vote up :)

Answer (score 4):

call the success method on onPostExecute method

Comment: success method is calling from connection class where i am doing my httprequest and parsing

Comment: You are calling from outside UI thread to update UI.call that method from onPostExecute.It is in the same UI thread