# Android - Controlling a listview inside a fragment, with buttons

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm building a tabbed application using Fragments and the compatibility support.

In one of the tabs, I want to have a listview. In this same tab, I have to button which would change the listview items (lets say each button would have an a string array assigned). 
I'm not figuring out how to do this. I already built the layout and clicklisteners for the buttons (which are working because I tested it with toast messages).

Can you give me an hint? Where would I put the listview code? On the OnClick? On OnCreateView?

Sorry, I dont have much experience with android.

This is my code for the fragment.

```
public class TabFragment6 extends ListFragment {
/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
 */
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
        // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist.  The fragment
        // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
        // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
        // won't be displayed.  Note this is not needed -- we could
        // just run the code below, where we would create and return
        // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
        return null;
    }



    LinearLayout theLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag6_layout, container, false);

    // Register for the Button.OnClick event GUITARRA
    Button bShopGuit = (Button)theLayout.findViewById(R.id.buttonshopguit);
    bShopGuit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           //abre setonclicklistener(
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(TabFragment6.this.getActivity(), "GUITAR button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });                                                                 //fecha )

    // Register for the Button.OnClick event BAIXO
            Button bShopBass = (Button)theLayout.findViewById(R.id.buttonshopbass);
            bShopBass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           //abre setonclicklistener(
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(TabFragment6.this.getActivity(), "BASS button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });                                                                 //fecha )

    return theLayout;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

???

First you have fragment. In it you have ListFragment with Adapter. In my projects im using AsyncTask to do the work for data and in it you can update list. Of cource adapter do this and you must notify it about data change.

This will help you [How to update listview after calling Asynctask to call webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922561/how-to-update-listview-after-calling-asynctask-to-call-webservice) , i think,